# How to join data from three different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three similar tables with same fields and one field has same values. Like

```
Table1(Column1:USA,Column2:200)

Table2(Column1:USA,Column2:400)

Table3(Column1:USA,Column2:500)
```

What I want is to query data Like this:

```
ColumnA  Table1Value   Table2Value   Table3Value

USA        200           400           500
```

I know database is not normalized, but I've to use the same as many parts of the application are already using this structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select
  t1.Column1 AS ColumnA,
  t1.Column2 AS Table1Value,
  t2.Column2 AS Table2Value,
  t3.Column3 AS Table3Value
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Column1 = t1.Column1
JOIN Table3 t3 ON t3.Column1 = t1.Column1
```

Comment: That will work as long as table2 and table 3 each have 1 record that matches table1. If they may not have any records then you need left joins. If they may have more than one record that matches, then you may need further disucssion of the requirements.

Comment: @HLGEM...I understand that completely but none of this was specified by OP.   I was simply providing the scenario that will work directly with the data and requirements provided.

Comment: Oh I'm not saying your answer is bad just letting the OP know there may be other considerations and his problem may be more complex. I did upvote you.